# Error al intentar usar Collections.sort sobre un ArrayList

Tags: java

```
Cuenta cuentaUno = new Cuenta(100,30,uno);
Cuenta cuentaDos = new Cuenta(80,30,dos);
Cuenta cuentaTres = new Cuenta(20,35,tres);
Cuenta cuentaCuatro = new Cuenta(120,150,cuatro);
Cuenta cuentaCinco = new Cuenta(0,200,cinco);

ArrayList<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList();
cuentas.add(cuentaUno);
cuentas.add(cuentaDos);
cuentas.add(cuentaTres);
cuentas.add(cuentaCuatro);
cuentas.add(cuentaCinco);

Collections.sort(cuentas);
```

*Quiero ordenar la lista pero en el sort me marca un error:*

> The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

Comment: ¿Y cómo deseas ordenar la lista...? ¿Por algún nombre o un valor numérico?

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado que la clase **Cuenta** implemente la clase interfaz **Comparable**? Sino, tendrías que agregar como segundo parámetro de ***Collections.sort(cuentas)*** un **comparador** de acuerdo al valor que especifiques...

Comment: [Ordenamiento de Objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) acá está el java doc para el ordenamiento de Objetos. El primer párrafo especifica que si se tratan de objetos de tipo *String* o *Date*, automáticamente se ordenarían (puesto que ambas clases implementan esa interfaz ***Comparable***).  También se especifica que si no implementas la clase, lanzaría un **ClassCastException**...

Comment: Si, faltaba implemetar comparable. Como recién empecé con este tema no ando muy fino aún. Gracias por la respuesta :)

Comment: ¡De nada! :) Asegúrate de marca la pregunta como respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te distes cuenta, el error se debe a que la clase `Cuenta` no implementa la interfaz `Comparable`.

Con esto dicho, en mi opinión, el implementar esa interfaz no es muy flexible porque asume que solo puedes ordenar la clase `Cuenta` de una manera. Pero a menudo necesitamos poder ordenar una clase de diferentes maneras según las circunstancias.

Por esto, usualmente lo veo más conveniente usar la versión de `Collections.sort` que acepta un `Comparator<T>`. Y si aprovechas bien la sintaxis de Java 8+, la llamada es muy legible y compacta.

Por ejemplo, digamos que tu clase `Cuenta` tiene una propiedad `getValor()` por la que deseas ordenar la lista. En vez de implementar la interfaz `Comparable`, simplemente puedes hacer la llamada de esta forma:

```
Collections.sort(cuentas, Comparator.comparing(Cuenta::getValor));
```

Comment: ¡Indudablemente más optimizado! :)

Answer (score 1):

Además de utilizar la interfaz **Comparable** para solucionarlo, recuerda que puedes utilizar:

```
Collections.sort(cuentas, new Comparator<Cuenta>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Cuenta cuenta1, Cuenta cuenta2) {
        return //<- el dato que quieres ordenar
    }
});
```

Así no tendrías que implementarla. Pero todo depende de si requieres usarlo siempre o no.